# Alternating clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/qVfy7/

HTML

```
<div id='button'></div>
<div id="mydiv">ko</div>
```

JS

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    $('#mydiv').text('ok');
});
```

CSS

```
#button{
    width:100px;
     height:100px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

On clicking the button, `mydiv`'s text changes. What I want to do, is clicking again on it to change the text back to `ko`, and so on, alternating between the two values. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just check what the text is, and return the other value to the text() method

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    $('#mydiv').text(function(_, txt) {
        return txt == 'ok' ? 'ko' : 'ok';
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/qVfy7/2/)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways, but one them is, make an `if-else`:

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    if($('#mydiv').text()=="ko")
        $('#mydiv').text('ok');
    else
        $('#mydiv').text('ko');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qVfy7/1/)**